# Unable to compile .java file using javac at Windows command prompt

Tags: java, apache, selenium, webdriver, apache-poi

I am trying to compile `LoginTest_Chrome.java` using `javac` at Windows command prompt. Prior to this, I have set my Environment's classpath to be associated with all the `.jar` library files, such as **Apache POI and Selenium**.

Using `echo %classpath%`, this is the result of my **classpath Environment**:

[image]

Then, I execute javac LoginTest.java and I got the following **result**:

[image]

Hope to have advice from experts here on how to resolve this issue which has bugged me for two days.

Error message after `javac *.java`:

```
Start.java:63: error: cannot find symbol tc = row.getCell(0).toString();
                                         ^ symbol: variable tc location: class Start
Start.java:64: error: cannot find symbol username = row.getCell(1).toString();
                                         ^ symbol: variable username location: class Start
Start.java:65: error: cannot find symbol password = row.getCell(2).toString();
                                         ^ symbol: variable password location: class Start
```

Comment: try with javac *.java command

Comment: Please copy output from console to the question text. Or embed image into the question.

Comment: Hi Kannan, Thank you for your advice. I have tried your suggestion, and it reduces from the initial 7 errors to 3 errors, which I believe is an improvement. However, there are still 3 remaining errors as follow:

Comment: Start.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
            tc = row.getCell(0).toString();
            ^
  symbol:   variable tc
  location: class Start
Start.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
            username = row.getCell(1).toString();
            ^
  symbol:   variable username
  location: class Start
Start.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
            password = row.getCell(2).toString();
            ^
  symbol:   variable password
  location: class Start

Comment: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Comment: HI setec, I have linked the output in the hyperlinked in my original posting. Thank you for your advice

Comment: My apologies for unable to paste the actual output as I tried to attach acreenshot, but can't do it in the comment section

Comment: BY the way, how different is running to javac *.java to javac <filename>.java? The former is to compile all java files available in the folder ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the compiler itself but with your source code. If you take a look at the first Error it says

```
LoginTest_Chrome.java:76: error cannot find symbol
   LoginCredentials.getFile();
```

which means that the `LoginCredentials` variable you are trying to use at line 76 wasn't declared somewhere, or it's somewhere the compiler can't see it (in another `.java` file maybe?)

All the other errors mean the same.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, Chris. I have tried to compiled it in Eclipse, and it's all fine. I could even execute my code. It is when I try to compile it via command prompt, that's when the problem occurs.

Comment: Of what files does you whole project consist? If for example you have one Class in a file named `Foo.java` and your main in another file named `Bar.java`, you have to execute `javac Foo.java Bar.java`. In your example you need at least `javac LoginTest_Chrome.java Start.java`

Comment: My project consists of ***LoginTest_Chrome.java*** which consist of the main method, and ***LoginCredentials.java***, to which ***LoginTest_Chrome.java*** will call. Base on your advise on the javac syntax, I should be compiling a non-main file followed by the main file ? Is there any imprtance to the order of compiling the files ? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: No there is no importance in the order. You should use `javac LoginTest_Chrome.java LoginCredentials.java` to compile your program. Although from the errors you posted in your question's comments I see you also have a `Start.java` class too maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the info, Chris. By the way, I have to apologise as I have cleared the code a bit and eliminate the Start class. However, still relavant to this issue, I will share a [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sS9gJWUgqLoh5XTAP2rc10er8ySNq9DXCjyM0Cnkju4/edit?usp=sharing) about my whole operation and issues. No obligation, though, but really appreciate your advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: It would really help if you posted the code you have written. My best guess is (if you are using an API inside one of those classes) that it needs all those generated classes and that's how you get them. I'm afraid I can't help you any further without the actual code. The above command should have worked.

Comment: You are most right, Chris. I should have known better. Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5ummyLW4FRrLVc3c21IVHFmS2M&usp=drive_web) to the source code. Thanks a lot !

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the libraries you are using, and since I'm missing them I can't help you further. Maybe take a look at the documentation of the library you are using, or find a tutorial regarding it.